# sed replace with newline acting as space in Groovy Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have a requirement to execute below in Jenkinsfile and it is working fine directly on the Server:

```
Server: echo $myval | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep analysisId | cut -d":" -f2

However, when I am trying to execute it in Jenkinsfile, it is treating newline as spaces, even though when I tried using '\' to supress '\':

Jenkinsfile: echo $myval | sed 's/,/\\n/g' | grep analysisId | cut -d":" -f2
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong ? Intent over here is that I am trying to parse JSON, and it's the only option I am left with

Value of myval

```
{"task":{"id":"AW1eTPbXXXXXXXX","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AWz2VsZM-CVpcXXXXXX","componentKey":"Sonar-Scanner-SFDX_CI-ProjectKey","componentName":"BV GitLAB Test Project","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AW1eTP3AX12345","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:05+0000","submitterLogin":"vgulati","startedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:07+0000","executedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:08+0000","executionTimeMs":1216,"logs":false,"hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization"}}
```

**Need to get Value of analysisId, which is AW1eTP3AX12345.**

Section of Jenkinsfile:

```
def analysisId = sh script: "echo $sonarUrlContent | sed 's/,/\\n/g' | grep analysisId | cut -d':' -f2",returnStdout:true
echo "analysisId: ${analysisId}"
```

Comment: Try to use native groovy jsonslurper to parse json. Please show the value of myval and desired result.

Comment: I tried jsonslurper but it doesn't work... I will soon update the query with expected outplut

Comment: Initial Question updated with all the details. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no way for you to install the Pipeline Utility Plugin, you can improvise some parsing of your own.

**This is a hacky hacky solution!** It only works since you only need one value:

```
def json = '{"task":{"id":"AW1eTPbXXXXXXXX","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AWz2VsZM-CVpcXXXXXX","componentKey":"Sonar-Scanner-SFDX_CI-ProjectKey","componentName":"BV GitLAB Test Project","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AW1eTP3AX12345","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:05+0000","submitterLogin":"vgulati","startedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:07+0000","executedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:08+0000","executionTimeMs":1216,"logs":false,"hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization"}}'
def data = json.split(",")

data.each{ item ->
    if(item.startsWith('"analysisId"')){
       result = item.split(":")[1].replace('"', '') 
    }
}

echo "$result"
```

Using readJSON would be preferable in any case, but this should work.

Comment: I tried something yesterday that worked for me, but again that didn't look efficient. This looks far better than that. I will try it out and update you

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the sed command fails, but if you want to parse JSON like @daggett implied you should use the jenkins native [readJSON](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) method instead of the groovy jsonSlurper

You have to install the Pipeline Utility Plugin and can use it like this:

```
def json = '{"task":{"id":"AW1eTPbXXXXXXXX","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AWz2VsZM-CVpcXXXXXX","componentKey":"Sonar-Scanner-SFDX_CI-ProjectKey","componentName":"BV GitLAB Test Project","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AW1eTP3AX12345","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:05+0000","submitterLogin":"vgulati","startedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:07+0000","executedAt":"2019-09-23T13:26:08+0000","executionTimeMs":1216,"logs":false,"hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization"}}'

def data = readJSON text: json
echo "$data.task.analysisId"
```

readJSON returns a groovy map which can be used like one would expect.

Comment: I had answered in the comment directly but my reputation wasn't enough, sorry

Comment: Hello smelm, Can you please suggest how would it go seeing the question. And does it have any library to import ? I tried few things but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @VarunSFDC I changed my answer to fit the example you have given.

Comment: Hello @smelm.. I tried it but looks like we need Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin to implement "readJSON ". 

Unfortunately I don't have rights to enable it for my job. Can you please share any workaround or any other solutions for my case ?

Comment: @VarunSFDC that is to bad. If you possibly can convince the admin to install the plugin that would be preferable to any solution I can offer now. That said I will make another answer only using the core Pipeline steps